# Docker image size changed on aws ecr

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, aws-ecr

i just uploaded docker image to aws ecr. my actual docker image locally is 927 MB while on ECR it is showing 321 MB

is there anything i am missing to read during documentation ?

i have uploaded image is proper with tag name but size change is there

Comment: Do you see "untagged" images in the column "image tags" from your ECR?

Comment: @JulianDidier no..there is image with uploaded name and latest tag

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is due to how docker client acts before it pushes the image to ECR, So the size on the ECR dashboard is a size for a compressed version of your image as [documented](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/repository-info.html):

> Beginning with Docker version 1.9, the Docker client compresses image layers before pushing them to a V2 Docker registry. The output of the docker images command shows the uncompressed image size, so it may return a larger image size than the image sizes shown in the AWS Management Console.

Answer (score 0):

Before few time ago aws was not showing the size option at ECR service now it is availble but

from aws side it is compressing images or something else to ECR when i pulled my image to local machine and checked size it was same as older one i have created locally.

So aws ecr is showing compressed size or may be some bug but docker image is working absolutely fine.